# bad request while converting curl request as python code

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

I am trying to convert the following curl request to python@3.8 code. The curl sends an excel file data to the server.

The curl requests are parsed properly but my python code is not working and I get a bad request back from the server.

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/rest/2.0/import/ejob" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic xyz" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "deleteFile=" -F "simulation=" -F "fileName=import_file" -F "sheetName=" -F "headerRow=" -F "sendNotification=" -F "sheetIndex=" -F "fileId=" -F 'template= [ { "resourceType": "xyz", "type": { "name": "xyz" }, "identifier": { "name": "${1}", "domain": { "name": "xyz", "community": { "name": "test" } } } } ]' -F "batchSize=10000" -F "file=@filename.xlsx;type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

Python Code :

```
url = "http://localhost:8080/rest/2.0/import/ejob"

payload={'deleteFile': '',
'simulation': '',
'fileName': 'xyz',
'sheetName': '',
'headerRow': '',
'sendNotification': '',
'sheetIndex': '',
'fileId': '',
'template': ' [ { "resourceType": "Asset", "type": { "name": "xyz" }, "identifier": { "name": "${1}", "domain": { "name": "xyz", "community": { "name": "file" } } } } ]',
'batchSize': '10000',
'file': '@filename.xlsx;type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}
files = {'file': ('import_file', open('filename.xlsx', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', {'Expires': '0'})}

headers = {
  'accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic xyz',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

[image: Error as seen from wireshark for python code]

The boundary is not seen in Wireshark for requests sent from python. The below screenshot is for CURL

[image: I don't see boundary in my python request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with passing 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' in header. I removed the file from payload and modified the header to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic xyz',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}

files = {
    'deleteFile': (None, ''),
    'simulation': (None, ''),
    'fileName': (None, 'import_file'),
    'sheetName': (None, ''),
    'headerRow': (None, ''),
    'sendNotification': (None, ''),
    'sheetIndex': (None, ''),
    'fileId': (None, ''),
    'template': (None, ' [ { "resourceType": "xyz", "type": { "name": "xyz" }, "identifier": { "name": "${1}", "domain": { "name": "xyz", "community": { "name": "test" } } } } ]'),
    'batchSize': (None, '10000'),
    'file': ('filename.xlsx;type', open('filename.xlsx;type', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/rest/2.0/import/ejob', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say for certain without knowing what server you are sending the request to, but I am guessing that your problem is that you are duplicating the `file` form field in the `data` and `files` parameters.

When you use the same key in the dicts passed to the `data` and `files` parameters, Requests will use multipart encoding for the request, and use the data from both of the dicts.

For example, when I tried the following code on my system:

```
requests.post("http://localhost:8000", data={"file": "foo"}, files={"file": "bar"})
```

It translated to the following HTTP request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: python-requests/2.24.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 231
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=2756042e934999f01bd91212ac4ae994

--2756042e934999f01bd91212ac4ae994
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

foo
--2756042e934999f01bd91212ac4ae994
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file"

bar
--2756042e934999f01bd91212ac4ae994-
```

In your case, it might be that the server saw the first `file` form field in your HTTP request, saw that it had no `filename` attribute, and decided to reject the request as badly formed.

Instead, try deleting the `file` key from the `payload` dictionary so that there is only one `file` form field in the resulting HTTP request.

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080/rest/2.0/import/ejob"
payload = {
    "deleteFile": "",
    "simulation": "",
    "fileName": "xyz",
    "sheetName": "",
    "headerRow": "",
    "sendNotification": "",
    "sheetIndex": "",
    "fileId": "",
    "template": ' [ { "resourceType": "Asset", "type": { "name": "xyz" }, "identifier": { "name": "${1}", "domain": { "name": "xyz", "community": { "name": "file" } } } } ]',
    "batchSize": "10000",
}
files = {
    "file": (
        "import_file",
        open("filename.xlsx", "rb"),
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        {"Expires": "0"},
    )
}
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic xyz",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

---

By the way, part of the problem is that you are using `@filename.xlsx` in the `file` key of the Python `payload` dict, but `@` is special curl syntax that includes the contents of the specified file in the request.

From the [curl man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html):

> -F, --form <name=content>
>
> (HTTP SMTP IMAP) For HTTP protocol family, this lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.
>
> For SMTP and IMAP protocols, this is the mean to compose a multipart mail message to transmit.
>
> This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.

In the Requests library, `@` does not have this effect; instead it is just inserted into the request as a normal character.